# Does Powershell Invoke-WebRequest throws error on download failure?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I wonder if Powershell Invoke-WebRequest will throw client side errors on a download request, such as disk full?

For instance:

```
 # Download recording
        try {
            $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
            $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $jwtURL -OutFile $outfile
            $a = [int]$r.StatusCode
        }
        catch {
            $a = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
        }
```

Would the code above get only http status code, or also write errors on the local file system?

Comment: You have to code for that and that is what try/catch is for.

Comment: See my edits....................

Comment: If there's a "disk full" error, the exception will not be a `WebException` and it won't have a `Response` property. Your `catch` does not filter any exception types, so it will still be invoked regardless of the kind of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from the comments to here as this is too long for comments

Remember there are error types. Terminating and non-terminating. Not every error is terminating so, you have to force that as well.

See this article: [Powershell Try Catch Tutorial & Guide](https://www.webservertalk.com/powershell-try-catch-tutorial-guide)

so, stuff like this example:

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

try {$res = $req.GetResponse()} 
catch [System.Net.WebException] 
{$res = $_.Exception.Response}
$res.StatusCode
```